# Colorbox with Star Rating Script

Tags: jquery, colorbox, rating-system

i use the Colorbox http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ and want to integrate a Star Rating Script http://boedesign.com/blog/2007/02/18/ajax-star-rating/ in the '#cboxTitle'.

After many attempts it works with '$("#inline_content").appendTo("#cboxTitle")' like shown in the script.
The problem is that i dont get the right Imageid of the actually shown image for the Star Rating Script in 'echo pullRating($imageid,...' in the div with the inline_content.

In this case i only get the Imageid from the last image in the database...

The div with the inline_content in the while-loop destroys my layout, and the 'pullRating' function inside the
'title: function(){' of the Gallery dont work.

Any ideas how to get the right Imageid for the Star Rating Script or is there a better way to integrate the Star Rating in the Colorbox?

Thank you very much for any suggestions!

```
<div style="float:left;width:820px;">
<ul class="gallerx">
<?php
$query = "SELECT imageid, name, url, thumburl, title FROM images";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
$name = $row['name'];
$imageid = $row['imageid'];
$imageurl = $row['url'];
$thumburl = $row['thumburl'];
$imagetitle = $row['title'];
?>

<li style="width:120px;height:80px;"><a class="gallery" href="<?php echo $imageurl;?>" title="<?php echo $imagetitle; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumburl; ?>" style="max-width:80px; max-height:80px;" title="<?php echo $imagetitle; ?>"></a></li>

<?php
}
?>
</ul>   
</div>


    <div style='display:none'>
        <div id='inline_content'>
        <div style="margin:30px 0 0 200px;width:220px;"><?php echo pullRating($imageid,true,false,true,NULL); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>  


<script type="text/javascript">
$('a.gallery').colorbox({
rel:'gallery', 
transition:"none", 
width:"75%", 
height:"75%",

title: function(){
return $("#inline_content").appendTo("#cboxTitle"); 
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating the photos with php, read actual photo id from sql and put the id in session.
When you rating the photo, read id from session an update rating by actual id.